# ～んだね as command

Tags: word-choice, words

Can you use it that way? 逃げるんだ and 逃げるんだよ are both acceptable commands (if rather forceful), but could you say 逃げるんだね for a softer but still very forceful command (or 逃げるんだな)?

Comment: What makes you think 逃げるんだ and 逃げるんだよ are rather forceful?

Answer (score 5):

You could use 逃げるんだね as a command, but I don't think you should use it. Here are the reasons.

1. The phrase is commanding the listener to escape, but it also has an extra nuance that the speaker is not concerned about the result the listener's escape, or the speaker thinks the listener can't do it. It sounds ironic.
2. 逃げるんだね also sounds like asking a question depending on the context. If you say せいぜい逃げるんだね。, you are commanding to escape. And if you say, [結局]{けっきょく}逃げるんだね。 you are asking a question. (which means "Are you finally escaping?")

If you want to say 逃げるんだ in a more formal way, you can say 逃げてください。